# How to show the Date from json data file Api Call using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to show the Date from json data file  Api Call using javascript?

I'm not able to show the date on the dashboard display page.

I'm using Javascript with async-await to call api, Bootstrap 4 for design
Is show function Date() {[native code]}.

I've attached images for reference.

```js
//data.json

{

"AllSchoolDetail": {
         "TotalStaff": 4500,
         "TotalStudents": 4000,
         "TotalTeachingStaff": 2530,
         "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 2500,
         "TotalAbsentStaff": 0,
         "TotalAbsentStudents": 0
    },

    "details": [
        {
            "Name": "abc",
            "TotalStaff": 10,
            "TotalStudents": 50,
            "TotalTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalAbsentStaff": 9,
            "TotalAbsentStudents": 10,
            "Date": "2020-06-01T11:09:18Z"
        },
         {
            "Name": "abc",
            "TotalStaff": 10,
            "TotalStudents": 50,
            "TotalTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalAbsentStaff": 9,
            "TotalAbsentStudents": 10,
            "Date": "2020-06-01T11:09:18Z"
        },
         {
            "Name": "abc",
            "TotalStaff": 10,
            "TotalStudents": 50,
            "TotalTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalAbsentStaff": 9,
            "TotalAbsentStudents": 10,
            "Date": "2020-06-01T11:09:18Z"
        },
        {
            "Name": "abc",
            "TotalStaff": 10,
            "TotalStudents": 50,
            "TotalTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalAbsentStaff": 9,
            "TotalAbsentStudents": 10,
            "Date": "2020-06-01T11:09:18Z"
        },
         {
            "Name": "abc",
            "TotalStaff": 10,
            "TotalStudents": 50,
            "TotalTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalNonTeachingStaff": 25,
            "TotalAbsentStaff": 9,
            "TotalAbsentStudents": 10,
            "Date": "2020-06-01T11:09:18Z"
        } 
    ],

 "Date": "2020-06-01T02:09:18Z"

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Navbar start -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <button
                class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#myNavbar"
            >
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2 nav-active">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link" id="gbl">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
                        <a href="#help" class="nav-link" id="in">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
                        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Navbar Ends -->
  <!--AllSchoolDetail  -->
  
  
  <!--AllSchoolDetail ends  -->
        <!--data starts  -->
        <h5 class="text-center p-5"><u> School Details</u></h5>



 <div id="output"></div>


         <div class="container my-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 gutters">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                    <div id="op"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- data ends -->

        <!-- footer starts -->
        <footer class="footer mt-5 py-3 bg-dark">
            <div class="container text-center"></div>
        </footer>
        <!-- footer ends -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /* */
    //AllSchoolDetail
async function getInfo() {
                const jsondata = await fetch("./js/data.json");
                const jsdata = await jsondata.json();
                var alldata = jsdata.AllSchoolDetail;
                let output = `
                <div class="container my-5">
              <h5 class="text-center p-5"><u> AllSchoolDetail </u></h5>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h5>TotalStaff</h5>
                            <p id="TotalStaff">${alldata.TotalStaff}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h5>TotalStudents</h5>
                            <p id="TotalStudents">${alldata.TotalStudents}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h5>TotalTeachingStaff</h5>
                            <p id="TotalTeachingStaff">${alldata.TotalTeachingStaff}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="container my-5">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h5>TotalNonTeachingStaff</h5>
                            <p id="TotalNonTeachingStaff">${alldata.TotalNonTeachingStaff}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 ">
                            <h5>TotalAbsentStaff</h5>
                            <p id="TotalAbsentStaff">${alldata.TotalAbsentStaff}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h5>TotalAbsentStudents</h5>
                            <p id="TotalAbsentStudents">${alldata.TotalAbsentStudents}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
                    <footer class="blockquote-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted text-center" >
                            ${Date}
                        </small>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>

                </div>
                `;
                document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = output;
            }
            getInfo();
    
    
    /*  */
    
 /*javascript for fetch data form Api*/

            const API_URL = `js/data.json`;
            const op = document.querySelector("#op");
            
            async function getData() {
                op.innerHTML = "";

                const response = await fetch(API_URL);
                const json = await response.json();
                json.details.forEach((schoolDetail) => {
                    op.innerHTML += `
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title card-header">
                    Name ${schoolDetail.Name}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        School Code: ${schoolDetail.SchoolCode}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Staff: ${schoolDetail.TotalStaff}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Students: ${schoolDetail.TotalStudents}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Teaching Staff: ${schoolDetail.TotalTeachingStaff}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Non -Teaching Staff: ${schoolDetail.TotalNonTeachingStaff}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Absent Staff: ${schoolDetail.TotalAbsentStaff}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Total Absent Students: ${schoolDetail.TotalAbsentStudents}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <small class="text-muted">Date:${schoolDetail.Date}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
    `;
                });
            }

            getData();
            
    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is not a proper way to call api calls. I tried to get it.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

Comment: well... as far as I see the `Date` is not in `json.details` but in `json`... also, your snippet doesn't work... if you provide an example make sure it shows the issue of the question and not some other issue ;)

Comment: try replacing date with timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `${Date}` with `${jsdata.Date}`

`Date` is the default javascript `Date()` function, That explains why you see `function Date() {[native code]}` instead of your string Date.

Comment: Thanks, for Solution.

One more problem is there Image3 is wrong one the correct one is the image 4 but not able create columns on api call.
image 4 shown for prototype above one

Comment: You can easily add `class="row"` to the `<div id="op"></div>` tag to make your grid work.